# Angular CLI environments not working

Tags: angular, tfs, angular-cli

I am working on doing some automated deployments and have discovered that the environment argument isn't doing anything currently on my ng build command. We are currently using ^4.0.0 of the Angular framework and targeting 1.5.2 of the CLI. I've verified that the environment classes are set up right per http://tattoocoder.com/angular-cli-using-the-environment-option/  and I have run the ng build command every way I can think

```
ng build --prod
ng build -prod
ng build --env=prod
```

Here is an example of the environment code we are using:

```
//DEV
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    envName: 'dev'
};

//PROD
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    envName: 'prod'
};
```

And then here is the environment code from our angular-cli.json

```
 "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
  "environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
```

ect. Any help or insights would be very much appreciated. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: How are you using the environment values in your application?  Was it using the dev version properly, and you're only having issues in production?

Comment: We are configuring a service to use a different URL depending on the environment. This has worked previously, however I have explored all the major differences between versions to no avail

Comment: Can you post some code of your environment files, and how you're using them in your service (import, etc), or make an example of how you're using it via https://stackblitz.com trying to duplicate the error?

Comment: I've updated the post to include some code, please let me know if you need more. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: How in your application are you accessing the environment variables?  For example, are you importing the environment like `import { environment } from '../environments/environment';` and using it in your components like `environment.envName` and getting no value?

Comment: I am importing it like you say, but regardless of the build argument I am only getting the values for DEV.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue as @MacKenzieMickelsen. After hours of Googleing I haven't found any solution. Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I found that I had to uninstall and reinstall the Angular CLI. That worked like a charm for me. Hope it helps you to.

Comment: This also seems to do nothing

Comment: Instead of adding your variables inside the const, create an export const:

`export const environment = {
  production: true
};

export const ENV_NAME = 'prod';`

The same for DEV (or all the other environments).

Then, import like this:

`import {ENV_NAME} from '../environments/environment';`